# How do I add annotations to Enums in the $metadata page of a .net Odata web api

Tags: c#, .net, enums, odata, metadata

I have an odata web api, built in .net.  The $metadata page is automatically generated by setting the ODataConventionModelBuilder in the register event.

I have a simple enum that looks like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum Appliance : Int64
{
    Stove = 1,
    Washer = 2,
    Dryer = 4,
    Microwave = 8
}
```

This simple enum appears like this in the $metadata page:

```
<EnumType Name="Appliance" IsFlags="true" UnderlyingType="Edm.Int64">
    <Member Name="Stove" Value="1"/>
    <Member Name="Washer" Value="2"/>
    <Member Name="Dryer" Value="4"/>
    <Member Name="Microwave" Value="8"/>
</EnumType>
```

However, I would like the enum to also have annotations when it appears in the $metadata page.  So it would look like this (notice the annotation tag):

```
<EnumType Name="Appliance" IsFlags="true" UnderlyingType="Edm.Int64">
    <Member Name="Stove" Value="1">
        <Annotation String="Stove Top" Term="FooBar"/>
    </Member>
    <Member Name="Washer" Value="2">
        <Annotation String="Washing Machine" Term="FooBar"/>
    </Member>
    <Member Name="Dryer" Value="4"/>
    <Member Name="Microwave" Value="8"/>
</EnumType>
```

Is there way of declaring my C# enum to generate this appearance?  If not, is there a way to programaticaly manipulate the ODataConventionModelBuilder OR it's EdmModel to insert these annotations?  Perhaps by using an attribute on the c# enum values?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@ArdAtak Yes. You can call ODL APIs to add the annotation after you get the `IEdmModel` from the `ODataConventionModelBuilder`.

For example:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EnumType<Appliance>();
IEdmModel edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();

// Create a customize term and add it into the model.
EdmTerm term = new EdmTerm("NS", "FooBar", EdmCoreModel.Instance.GetString(true));
((EdmModel)edmModel).AddElement(term);

var member = enumType.Members.First(c => c.Name == "Stove");

// Apply the annotation to the member with the new built term.
EdmVocabularyAnnotation annotation = new EdmVocabularyAnnotation(member, term, new EdmStringConstant("Stove Top"));
annotation.SetSerializationLocation(model, EdmVocabularyAnnotationSerializationLocation.Inline); // OutOfLine can't work for the 'EnumMember'.
((EdmModel)edmModel).SetVocabularyAnnotation(annotation);
```

Then, you can get the following CSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema Namespace="AnnotationEnumType.Models" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <EnumType Name="Appliance" UnderlyingType="Edm.Int64" IsFlags="true">
                <Member Name="Stove" Value="1">
                    <Annotation Term="NS.FooBar" String="Stove Top" />
                </Member>
                <Member Name="Washer" Value="2" />
                <Member Name="Dryer" Value="4" />
                <Member Name="Microwave" Value="8" />
            </EnumType>
        </Schema>
        <Schema Namespace="Default" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <EntityContainer Name="Container" />
        </Schema>
        <Schema Namespace="NS" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <Term Name="FooBar" Type="Edm.String" />
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Hope it can help. Please leave your comments or send email to me if you have further questions. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Sam.  I found a workaround by intercepting the metadata request and injecting XML nodes into it.  I've moved on to a different layer of the application but will need to return to the enum layer in a little while to finalize the implementation.  I will try your suggestion at that time and see how it works.  Thank you so much for going through the effort to provide a detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks @Sam Xu,  your solution looks good except for 1 issue: 

The 6th line of code in your C# is

var member = enumType.Members.First(c => c.Name == "Stove");

However, enumType is not defined in any of the above lines of code.  Can you shed some light on this?  Thanks.

Comment: @ArdAtak The enumType is built from the model builder. see `builder.EnumType<Appliance>();`, where, the `Appliance` is the CLR enum type defined in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sam,
Here's the final method that adds annotations to enum members based on their "Description" attribute:

```
    private static void AddAnnotations(ref IEdmModel model, ODataConventionModelBuilder builder)
    {
        string enumName;
        string fullName;
        string memberName;
        string description;
        CustomAttributeData att;

        foreach (var enumTypeConfig in builder.EnumTypes)
        {
            foreach (var memberInfo in enumTypeConfig.ClrType.GetMembers())
            {
                if (memberInfo.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType.Name == "DescriptionAttribute"))
                {
                    enumName = enumTypeConfig.Name;
                    fullName = enumTypeConfig.FullName;
                    memberName = memberInfo.Name;

                    att = memberInfo.CustomAttributes.Where(a => a.AttributeType.Name == "DescriptionAttribute").Single();
                    description = att.ConstructorArguments[0].Value.ToString();

                    EdmTerm term = new EdmTerm("RESO.OData.Metadata", "StandardName", EdmCoreModel.Instance.GetString(true));  //TODO:  This will need to 1 of 2 choices depending on if Enum is standard or extended.
                    ((EdmModel)model).AddElement(term);

                    EdmEnumType enumType = (EdmEnumType)model.SchemaElements.First(e => e.FullName() == fullName);
                    var member = enumType.Members.First(c => c.Name == memberName);

                    EdmVocabularyAnnotation annotation = new EdmVocabularyAnnotation(member, term, new EdmStringConstant(description));
                    annotation.SetSerializationLocation(model, EdmVocabularyAnnotationSerializationLocation.Inline);
                    ((EdmModel)model).SetVocabularyAnnotation(annotation);
                }
            }
```